# How can I upload video to a specific YouTube channel using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to post a video to one of my brand Youtube accounts.
But when I use apps script, I cannot choose to what channel video should be uploaded.

May be there is any way to specify channel, or use brand accounts to upload videos?

Here is my code:

```
function PostVideoToYT(channel_id, video_url, title, description) {
  const sourceFile = UrlFetchApp.fetch(video_url, { muteHttpExceptions: true }).getBlob();
  const videoResource = {
    snippet: {
      title: title,
      description: description,
      channelId:"UCNywJdNO5K6edWupWD6opVw",
    },
    status: { privacyStatus: 'private' },
  };
  const newVideo = YouTube.Videos.insert(videoResource, "snippet,status", sourceFile);  // Modified
  Logger.log(newVideo)
  return newVideo;
}
```

How can I specify channel id?

Comment: When you authorize the script it should ask you what channel you want to authorize it to be able to access.  Did you chose the correct channel?

Comment: @DaImTo I can authorize only with my own (main) account, When i try to choose needed one, I got an error https://prnt.sc/2xJe63QubJlC https://prnt.sc/IrOTweNJB5F5

Brand account was created yesterday, maybe I need to change some settings?